# Report Network errors in PagedList.BoundaryCallback

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-paging

I have a working paging mechanism with Database (room) as single source of truth. I also have retrofit as network library and I use RxPagedListBulder to keep all the stuffs bound and running.

However, I cannot find a way to pass back my response to the View, since network stuffs ends with inserting in the database in case of success. I cannot find a way to report network error, and the topic is not well addressed in the available tutorials

The Working code is found on [github repo](https://github.com/mtangoo/Kasuku-Muvi) for those who want to understand this question fully. [The Boundary callback is here](https://github.com/mtangoo/Kasuku-Muvi/blob/master/app/src/main/java/tz/co/hosannahighertech/kasukumuvi/data/repos/ListBoundaryCallback.java)

Comment: can you explain a little bit what you mean?

Comment: I have room, and yes, I have read all those. My problem is how to report error (and  progress) since my RxJava calls are inside repo class and repo get called by VieModel. I will update the question

Comment: Have you tried LiveData? Retrofit Callback > MutableLiveData > ViewModel > UI

Comment: can you expand it a little bit? The source code is here: https://github.com/mtangoo/Kasuku-Muvi/blob/master/app/src/main/java/tz/co/hosannahighertech/kasukumuvi/data/repos/ListBoundaryCallback.java

You can see how I have implemented it. PR will definitely be appreciated

Comment: Sorry @Stefano, I'm new and **don't have much authority** on these topics, however, from high level perspective, catch the errors within the retrofit callback using a `MutableLiveData`:


``Callback<Api> {
  void onFailure(..., Throwable t) {
       livedataError.setValue(t)
    }
}``
Get the only `LiveData` in the viewmodel class, and observe it within the UI and do something when it changes. For more detailed implementation see the [developers guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html#addendum)

Comment: Forgot to mention that the high level perspective example is from [Paging overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/#network-with-database-data-arch) Network and Database example. To my understanding Retrofit callback is done within `BoundaryCallback`, catching the errors with `MutableLiveData` and then passing the mutated data as `LiveData` to ViewModel, then to UI. [Paging GitHub example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/PagingWithNetworkSample) can be useful too.